# Which Google Cloud function is preferable to fetch data from external API into GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl

This should be a very easy question but I can't wrap my head around what to use. I would like to create a data pipeline that fetches data from an outside/external API (for example, Spotify API) and perform some rather simple data cleaning on it, while either continue to create a JSON file in Cloud Storage or enter the data into BigQuery.

As far as I understand I can use Composer to do it, using DAGS etc but what I need here is something more simple/lightweight (mainly UI based) that doesn't cost as much as Composer does as well as being easier to use. What I am looking for is something like Data Factory in Azure.

So, in brief:

- Login to a data source using username/password
- Extract data from a well known format (CSV/Json)
- Transform data, such as remove columns, perform simple filtering like date filtering.
- Reformat the data into another format (JSON/CSV/BigQuery)
  ...without having to code everything from scratch.

Can I handle all of this with one GCP application or do I need to use combinations like Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Functions etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, you have several options...

Cloud Scheduler seems to be a requirement to trigger regularly the process (up to every minutes).

Then, you have 2 options:

- Code the process: API Call, transform/clean the data, sink the data into the destination
- Use Cloud Workflow: you can define the API calls that you want to do

  - Call the API
  - Store the raw data in BigQuery (API Call also, you have connectors to simplify the process)
  - Run a query in BigQuery to clean/format your data and store them into a final table (API Call also)

You can also perform a mix between Cloud Functions to get the data and clean/format the data with a query in BigQuery.

---

*Doing something specific like that without starting from scratch... difficult...*

---

**EDIT 1**

If you have a look to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/quickstart-console), you can see that sample

```
- getCurrentTime:
    call: http.get
    args:
      url: https://us-central1-workflowsample.cloudfunctions.net/datetime
    result: currentTime
- readWikipedia:
    call: http.get
    args:
      url: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
      query:
        action: opensearch
        search: ${currentTime.body.dayOfTheWeek}
    result: wikiResult
- returnResult:
    return: ${wikiResult.body[1]}
```

The first step `getCurrentTime` performs an external call and store the result in `result: currentTime`.

In the next step, you can reuse the result `currentTime` and get only the value that you want in another API call.

And you can plug steps like that.

If you need authentication, you can perform a call to secret manager to get the secret values and then to result the secret manager call result in subsequent steps.

For an easier connection to Google APIs, you can use [connectors](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/connectors)

Comment: Thanks. When you write Cloud Workflow, do you mean Cloud Workflows (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/workflows.googleapis.com)? I have never heard it being mentioned in this manner. Or did you by any chance mean Cloud Dataflow?

Comment: I have, by the way, a system to fetch CSV's etc working in Node.js, so this is mainly about exploring the possibilities of Google Cloud (I don't necessarily need to code, but if mundane fetching/cleaning tasks can be solved by Cloud apps, why not?). I understand that Scheduler+Functions is a possibility (as well as Composer) but it seems like one out of Cloud Fusion, Dataprep, Dataflow or the likes of it would work as well - but I can't really figure out what separates them.

Comment: Cloud datafusion, and dataflow have been excluded if you find Composer too expensive (and you are right, it's too expensive!!). Cloud Workflow is a lightweight orchestrator that allows you to define the successive API calls to perform with control flow (loops, condition, branching,...). That's why, if you perform only API calls, and you don't want to code, define, in YAML, your workflow and let the magic happen.

Comment: Thanks, once again. When you write Cloud Workflow, do you refer to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/workflows.googleapis.com/, or something else? I have had a look at it but can't see how Cloud Workflows can access external API:s such as Spotify API). Is it supposed to be able to act like Postman and login/fetch data from url, and transfer that data to e.g. Cloud Storage? Or is this something that always have to be coded?

Comment: I updated the answer. I tried to explain the basic concept of Workflow.

Comment: Thanks! I also now realized I had been looking into Workflows API in Marketplace which was very confusing, I now saw the actual service/application and it makes much more sense. I will try this out, but it looks exactly like what I am looking for.